# Is there a way to change the axis labels?

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

i'm updating some code in my job and got in a problem, on amcharts3, the labels of the x axis are not what the data is binded to. Like the data of the chart is binded to a date, but shows another value (the value is in the dataset) in the labels, and didn't find a way to do that on amcharts4.

I tried creating another x axis but then the data doesn't look right.

It should be a x axis showing a value that is in the dataset but just showing, the axis should be binded to another value in the dataset. if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an amCharts v3 example that uses `labelFunction` to, as you say, bind data to what gets written out on the axis (courtesy [xorspark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6106614/xorspark)):

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/74df55e029228d9a1867b65f351ca48f

For v4, you would use an [Adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) on the `AxisLabel`. A tricky part with DateAxis Axis Labels is that their `dataItem` doesn't tie to the original chart or series' `DataItem` to give you access to the rest of the data (e.g. via `dataItem.dataContext["field name here"]`). So as the adapter tries to provide `text` to its DateAxis `AxisLabel`, if that label has a `Date`, you'll have to compare said `AxisLabel` to each of your data objects to see if its `Date` and your data's date (if it's a string, convert it to `Date`) match. If it does, then pull from that data's field that you want to "bind" it to.

Relevant code (presuming your data field for dates is `"date"`):

```js
function dataToDate(dateStr) {
  return chart.dateFormatter.parse(dateStr);
}
function sameDates(date1, date2) {
  return date1.getTime() === date2.getTime();
}
function matchAxisDateToData(axisLabel) {
  var length = chart.data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
    // there are more axis labels than we see, and some of them will return undefined for their date
    if (axisLabel.dataItem.dates.date && sameDates(axisLabel.dataItem.dates.date, dataToDate(chart.data[i].date))) {
      return chart.data[i].timeOfDay;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
dateAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", function(text, axisLabel) {
  var dataText;
  if (axisLabel.dataItem.dates.date) {
    dataText = matchAxisDateToData(axisLabel);
  }
  // if there's a match, return that, otherwise return the default "text"
  return dataText || text;
});
```

Here's a demo of the above:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/eb455855b460998f4e4282a0216a9443